# Syntax for implicit conversion from F# function to C# Func<>

Tags: f#

This compiles

```
let a (t2: Type) = obj()
let c: Func<Type,obj> = a
```

but this

```
let a (t2: Type) = obj()
let b (t:Type)  = a
let c: Func<Type,(Type->obj)> = b
```

says *This expression was expected to have type
'Func<Type,(Type -> obj)>'   but here has type
''a -> 'b -> obj'*

I know it is something simple, but my brain has thrown the towel in.

Answer (score 2):

The normal delegate conversion would be the following:

```
let c : System.Func<Type, Type, obj> = b
```

If you want to interpret `b` as a `Func` returning another function, you have to be explicit about it only having one input argument:

```
let a (t2: Type) = obj()
let b (t:Type)  = a
let c = Func<_, _>(b)
```

The [F# spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) has this to say about delegate conversions:

> [14.4]: If a formal parameter has delegate type D, an actual argument *farg* has known type
> *ty1 -> ... -> tyn -> rty*, and the number of arguments of the Invoke method of delegate type
> D is precisely n, interpret the formal parameter in the same way as the following:
> *new D(fun arg1 ... argn -> farg arg1 ... argn).*

So in other words, the implicit conversion to the Func delegate of your b function is the same as

```
let c = System.Func<_, _, _>(fun a1 a2 -> b a1 a2)
```

I think the reason for this is for interop with other dotnet languages and to be consistent with how curried functions are compiled:

> [8.13.4]: The compiled representation of a curried method member is a .NET method in which the arguments are concatenated into a single argument group.

Comment: I'm more interested in the type Func<Type,(Type->obj)>. If one hovers their cursor over the variable b, the expected F# signature of Type->(Type->obj) is shown. A Func<Type,Type,obj> is a different kettle of fish. An explicit conversion c = Func<Type,(Type->obj)>(b) works. I suspect the compiler cant differentiate between a (Type-Type-obj) and a (Type->(Type->obj)) as they can be essentially curried the same way and therefore it is an ambiguous conversion to a Func<>

Comment: Type->Type->obj and Type->(Type->obj) are indeed identical AFAIK. But I guess to ease interop with other dotnet languages the automatic conversion is Func<Type, Type, obj> and not Func<Type, Func<Type, obj>>. This is similar to how F# looks when called from C#: all curried arguments have become tuples.